# VBA Arrays in Word

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

I want to declare a dynamic string array, then make calls to each of the other procedures. This is what I have, I thought it would work but I keep getting errors.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

   Public ListArr() As String

   Application.Run "Get_Input_List"

End Sub

Function Get_Input_List(ByRef ListArr() As String) As String

   Dim list As String
   Dim MesBox As String

  list = InputBox("Please enters word to sort using a comma with no space to separate", "Words")

  ListArr = Split(list, ",")

  MsgBox ListArr(1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple issues here.  First, `Public` can only be used as an access modifier for Module level variables - not local ones, so it should be `Dim ListArr() As String`.  Second, you don't need to use `Application.Run` to call procedures in the same project.  If you *did*, you aren't passing the required parameter (which can't be passed `ByRef` via `Application.Run` anyway).  Third, `Get_Input_List` is a function, so you should probably return the result of the `Split`.  Right now it always returns `vbNullString`.  I'm guessing that you're looking for something more like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
   Dim ListArr() As String
   ListArr = Get_Input_List

   Dim inputWord As Variant
   For Each inputWord In ListArr
        MsgBox inputWord
   Next
End Sub

Function Get_Input_List() As String()
    Dim list As String

    list = InputBox("Please enter words to sort separated with a comma and no spaces", "Words")
    Get_Input_List = Split(list, ",")
End Function
```